# How to get list of files from a specific folder in internal storage?

Tags: android, file

With `listFiles()` I can get list of file in  `/data/data/package/files`.
How can I get list of files from directory like  `/data/data/package/myfolder` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

None of the above was exact and really worked, but it helped to get to the answer, Thanks.
The Answer to my problem is:

```
File mydir = context.getDir("myfolder", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);              
File lister = mydir.getAbsoluteFile();
for (String list : lister.list())
{
   //       
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Your application has a "Files" and "Caches" directory.  You can query this path with Context.getFilesDir() or Context.getCacheDir().

There is also a Context.getDir() function for private folders like "myfolder".

With the corrsponding File object, you can enumerate the files.

```
File dirFiles = mContext.getFilesDir();
for (String strFile : dirFiles.list())
{
 // strFile is the file name
}
```