# Get list of files in arbitrary subdirectory of Android internal (private) storage

Tags: java, android

This question has been asked, but no working answer has been proposed.  Someone asked and answered a similar question here: [How to get list of files from a specific folder in internal storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871925/how-to-get-list-of-files-from-a-specific-folder-in-internal-storage)  Unfortunately, the proposed answer (`getAbsoluteDir`) in fact returns a *new* file using the same path as the file provided.

So here it is again: I have the string name used to create a subdirectory (using `file.mkdir()`) that resides in my app's private internal storage (`/data/data/come.my.app/file`).  How do use that string name to list the files that reside in that subdirectory?  The only way I can come up with is to get the subdirectory's `File` object from the subdirectory name by looping through all the subdirectories in that app directory.  Surely there is a more direct way...

The reason why I'm doing this is I'm passing a reference to this directory (because of the files it contains) through a bundle (across Activities).  If there's a better way to do that, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the proposed answer (getAbsoluteDir) in fact returns a new file using the same path as the file provided.

Well, you could skip the `lister` line, and use `mydir.list()` instead. However, the code there does not "return" anything -- `list()` returns the files in a directory, and in that answer, it shows iteration over that list.

> How do use that string name to list the files that reside in that subdirectory?

You can use:

```
File dir=getDir(whateverYourStringNameIs);

dir.list();
```

Or:

```
File dir=new File(getFilesDir(), whateverYourStringNameIs);

dir.list();
```

Basically, get a `File` object on your directory (which you already know how to get, as you called `mkdir()` on one), then call `list()` to get the contents. Once you have the `File` object, the rest is standard Java I/O.

> The reason why I'm doing this is I'm passing a reference to this directory (because of the files it contains) through a bundle (across Activities).

Assuming that these are all your own activities, you could call `getAbsolutePath()` on your `File` to get a `String` for your `Bundle`. Then, on the other side, use `new File(bundle.getString("whateverYouCalledIt"))` to reconstitute the `File` object. Or, pass in the `Bundle`  a string that represents the relative path within your app's portion of internal storage, and use that with `getDir()` or `getFilesDir()` to build a `File` object pointing to that same path.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer.  And yes, I had already tried getDir (it seems to require a second arg, an int mode for read/write perms), and I couldn't get it to work -- apologies for not mentioning that.  But then I tried your second option -- constructing a new File object passing in the directory name -- and it worked!  Not sure why getDir isn't working.  PS: if this is the commonsware book author, your book is at the top of my list of Android books to buy -- I just started with Java on Android a few days ago (used Lua and Python on Android previously).

Comment: @EricS.Bullington: "I couldn't get it to work" -- I pretty much stick to `getFilesDir()` or other specific methods (e.g., `getDatabasePath()`). "if this is the commonsware book author" -- that would be me. "your book is at the top of my list of Android books to buy" -- thanks! :-)